# How to detect a closed loop created by TrailRenderer and then get gameobjects inside

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What method/formula can I use for closed loop detection & getting gameobjects in the closed loop

This is for a mobile game project on Android, with a TrailRenderer system in place

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Trigger Sphere Collider to detect objects inside a closed loop. Collider must be attached to the GameObject with the loop. Set the radius of the sphere and should be enough. Set a Tag for objects who should be detected inside loop and check if they are inside with OnTriggerEnter or OnTriggerStay etc.